# How can I save the serialized data into the meta field in MySQL?

Tags: wordpress

I am saving the PHP array in serialized format into the field. It saved the value in this format.

```
s:71:"a:5:{i:0;s:2:"70";i:1;s:2:"58";i:2;s:2:"46";i:3;s:2:"27";i:4;s:2:"24";}";
```

But I want to save the serialized data in this format

```
a:2:{i:0;i:20;i:1;i:28;}
```

In WordPress I use `update_post_meta($post_id, 'field_name', serialize( $array) )`

Is there any issue with the SQL?

Comment: Did you try it?  If you do what you suggest, it will store in database as `s:24:"a:2:{i:0;i:20;i:1;i:28;}";`

Comment: Yes i am saving in the required format but don't know how it saves it into this format
`s:24:"a:2:{i:0;i:20;i:1;i:28;}";`

Comment: if i print before saving it prints `a:2:{i:0;i:20;i:1;i:28;}`
but when i check in database it is like 
`s:24:"a:2:{i:0;i:20;i:1;i:28;}"`

Comment: Read this -> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/ `$meta_value (mixed) (Required) Metadata value. Must be serializable if non-scalar.` It automatically uses the wp function `maybeserialize` on the serialized array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function update_field from ACF works a little bit different from update_post_meta. Can you see it?

update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ); 
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );

If you use update_post_meta you should in my opinion use get_post_meta to get the meta. If you use update_field you should use the_field or get_field because ACF stores the key/values-pairs in a slightly different way.